# Clone an object when I have a pointer to its base class?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, inheritance

I have multiple classes (let's say B and C), which inherit some abstract base class (let's say A). I have a pointer (p1) to class A, which is actually pointing to an object (o1) of class B or class C. Then I have another pointer (p2) to class A and I want to make it point to another object (o2) that is the same as o1. The problem is that at that moment I don't know what type o1 is of.

```
A* newObject() //returns pointer to A which actually points to an object of class B or class C
{
     ....
}
A * p1 = newObject();
A * p2 = //I want it to point to a new object that is the same as the object p1 is pointing to. How can I do that?
```

I need that because I am implementing a genetic algorithm and I have multiple types of controlling classes which I then want to mutate. And when something replicates I want the child to be the same as the parent and then I want to mutate the child. This means that p2 cannot be equal to p1 because then this will mutate the controller of the parent as well.

Comment: Look for design pattern "Prototype". It describes how to "clone" objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add virtual method `Clone()` to the class.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;

    auto Clone() const { return std::unique_ptr<A>{DoClone()}; }
    // ...
private:
    virtual A* DoClone() const { return new A(*this); }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    auto Clone() const { return std::unique_ptr<B>{DoClone()}; }
    // ...
private:
    // Use covariant return type :)
    B* DoClone() const override { return new B(*this); }
    // ...
};

class C : public A {
public:
    auto Clone() const { return std::unique_ptr<C>{DoClone()}; }
    // ...
private:
    // Use covariant return type :)
    C* DoClone() const override { return new C(*this); }
    // ...
};
```

and then

```
auto p2 = p1->Clone();
```

Comment: Class A is abstract, so I don't think that `new A(*this)` is valid but otherwise thanks.

Comment: So `virtual A* DoClone() const = 0`.

Comment: What are the differences between the two versions (the one you first posted and this one with DoClone)? Also is there a need for `auto` isn't it done compile time, so using `auto` wouldn't help?

Comment: @indjev99: I use `DoClone` to only expose `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw owning pointers. And `auto` might be replaced by `std::unique_ptr<..>` if you prefer.